# How to assign object to field

Tags: c#

I don't know how to name that.

I have class looks like this:

```
class exampleClass
{
    string 1 = "Sth1";
    string 2 = "Sth2";
    string 3 = "Sth3";
    int tmp;
}
```

And i want to assign field in second class:

> obj = new exampleClass();
>
> obj.tmp = 3;

And in third class call out this tmp field:

```
if(obj.tmp == 3) show me string number 3 -> "Sth3".
```

In conclusion. I don't know how to associate this tmp with string. I want that would be a enum type or something.

Comment: You need to convert string number to an actual integer using int.Parse("3")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho a Dictionary should fit your needs

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
myDict.Add(1, "Sth1");
myDict.Add(2, "Sth2");
myDict.Add(3, "Sth3");

string Result = myDict[3]; //Sth3
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way of associating objects with small consecutive numbers is an array or a list:

```
class exampleClass {
    // An object associated with int value X goes into X-th position:
    private static readonly string[] Strings = new[] {"Sth1", "Sth2", "Sth3"};
    // Since tmp is used as an index, you need to protect assignments to it:
    private int tmp;
    public int Tmp {
        get { return tmp; }
        set {
            if (value < 0 || value >= Strings.Length) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            Tmp = value;
        }
    }
    public string GetString() {
        return Strings[tmp];
    }
}
```

Note the added setter for `Tmp`, which ensures that the caller cannot assign `tmp` a negative value or a value above the last allowed index in the array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for data structures.

What you have is multiple variables.  What you *want* is a collection.  Something like this:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public IList<string> Strings = new List<string> { "Sth0", "Sth1", "Sth2", "Sth3" };
}
```

Then you can refer to the elements by their index:

```
var obj = new ExampleClass();
obj.Strings[3] // <--- will be "Sth3"
```

If that index needs to be stored *on* the object for some reason, you can use the `int` you have now:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public IList<string> Strings = new List<string> { "Sth0", "Sth1", "Sth2", "Sth3" };
    public int CurrentIndex;
}
```

and...

```
var obj = new ExampleClass { CurrentIndex = 3 };
obj.Strings[obj.CurrentIndex] // <--- will be "Sth3"
```

Add more error checking, improve variable names (because given the current names it's *really* unclear what your overall goal even is here), even evolve this into a proper iterator structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of, note that `1`, `2` and `3` are not valid field names, or enum names. So let's call them `A`, `B` and `C` instead.

```
enum MyOption { A, B, C }


class MyClass
{
    public MyOption Option { get; set; }
}

var obj = new MyClass();
obj.Option = MyOption.A;

if(obj.Option == MyOption.A)
{
    // ...
}
```